# Chromium browser text too big on HiDPI Display

Tags: 14.04, chromium, dpi

I am running the Chromium browser on my Ubuntu 10.04 virtual machine. It seems that the text in the tabs and titles is over compensating for the HiDPI support and it looks too big.

Screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading. 10.04 came out six years ago.